# Unable to SSH, cannot create /dev/null/.ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, hadoop

I am trying to deploy hadoop with a master and slave node. But the master fails to start tasttracker and datanode processes in slaves, as it is not able to ssh into slaves. The error message is 'Could not create /dev/null/.ssh'. I am unable to figure out the cause of the problem.

Comment: /dev/null is the auto delete file for Linux. Whatever goes in, never comes out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device Why are you trying to put .ssh there? It should go in a users home directory. ~/.ssh http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux#Installing_your_public_key_automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message "can't create /dev/null/.ssh" indicates that the slave interprets "/dev/null" as the home directory of your hadoop user and then tries to create a ".ssh" directory there. Usually the purpose of the .ssh directory ist to store the authorized_keys file to allow for passwordless login.

On the slave review the /var/log/audit.log or /var/log/secure files to see what user Hadoop tries to ssh into the machine. Review that users home directory in /etc/passwd (c.f. man usermod or man vipw to change it).

Comment: After reading your comment, I looked into it and found that the user didn't have a home directory. I created a directory by being root as,
/home/nameofuser
After that I used /usr/sbin/usermod command to set that directory as home directory for nameofuser.
But the problem is that the user still doesn't write permission in the home directory. The ownership of the directory lies with root, as I created it as root. How do I transfer the ownership of the directory to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Consider these points as well while troubleshooting or if you face any more problems.

1. Check the home directory
2. Check the permissions of the authorized_keys file.